# Get Children of Parent Row

Tags: smartsheet-api, smartsheet-api-2.0

Is there any way to get all of the children of a parent row? The only method that I see, is to grab all of the rows and look at the parentId's assigned to the children.

(For what it is worth, I am using the javascript api)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe it's currently possible to explicitly request all child rows of a specified row, using the SmartSheet API.

As you've described in your post, you'd need to use the [Get Sheet](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?javascript#get-sheet) operation to get the list of all rows in the sheet, then look for row objects in that result set where `parentId` matches the `id` of the parent row you're interested in.